# Cart Throb Permissions: The requested module page could not be found

Tags: cartthrob, permissions

Does anyone out there have Cart Throb Permissions working as it should?  I have NEVER been able to get it working properly since I purchased it.

up2date EE 2.7.1 CartThrovb 2.4 and Permissions 2.3.3

I still get error:

```
The requested module page could not be found.
```

when click next page at the bottom of my permission module page.  I con only access the first 50 permissions and cannot view the next page.

Comment: actually found the issue.  When I did the upgrade the file Mbr_addon_builder.php was not deleted and it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

actually found the issue. When I did the upgrade the file Mbr_addon_builder.php was not deleted and it should have been.